# How to distinguish between HTTP requests sent by my client application and other requests from the Internet

Tags: security, http, network-protocols

Suppose I have an client/server application working over HTTP. The server provides a RESTy API and client calls the server over HTTP using regular HTTP GET requests.

The server requires *no* authentication. Anyone on the Internet can send a GET HTTP request to my server. It's Ok. I just wonder how I can *distinguish* between the requests from my client and other requests from the Internet.

Suppose my client sent a request X. A user recorded this request (including the agent, headers, cookies, etc.) and send it again with `wget` for example. I would like to distinguish between these two requests in the server-side.

Comment: In my opinion the best way to do it would be with a custom user agent string.

Comment: It can be easily faked.

Comment: I don't think there's any way to prevent a user from faking it, without authentication.

Comment: What if the client and server talk over HTTPS ? Would it help ?

Comment: If your client can send a request, so can anyone else. Basic authentication transmits the authentication in plain text and digest authentication can be MitM'ed so a user can alter the requests even if the client is closed source.

Comment: I think HTTPS would help if you used client certificates, though I don't know much about it: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/14589/advantages-of-client-certificates-for-client-authentication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot know for sure if it is your application or not. Anything in the request can be made up.

But, you can make sure that nobody is using your application inadvertently. For example somebody may create a javascript application and point to your REST API. The browser sends the Origin header ([draft](http://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-abarth-origin-09.html)) indicating in which application was the request generated. You can use this header to filter calls from applications that are not yours.

However, that somebody may use his own web server as proxy to your application, allowing him then to craft HTTP requests with more detail. In this case, at some point you would be able of pin point his IP address and block it.

But the best solution would be to put some degree of authorization. For example, the UI part can ask for authentication via login/password, or just a captcha to ensure the caller is a person, then generate a token and associate that token with the use session. From that point the calls to the API have to provide such token, otherwise you must reject them.

Answer (score 3):

There is no exact solution rather then authentication. On the other hand, you do not need to implement username & password authentication for this basic requirement. You could simply identify a random string for your "client" and send it to api over custom http header variable like ;

```
GET /api/ HTTP/1.1
Host: www.backend.com
My-Custom-Token-Dude: a717sfa618e89a7a7d17dgasad
...
```

You could distinguish the requests by this custom header variable and it's values existence and validity. But I'm saying "Security through obscurity" is not a solution.